# ctypevalidator array of integer validation

Tags: php, yii

how to validate array of integer in the model class?

**model class**

> array('marks_Mark','CTypeValidator','type'=>'array')

marks_Mark is an array.

**view**

> echo $form->textField($model,'marks_Mark[]',array('value'=>$value->marks_Mark,'size'=>10,'maxlength'=>3));

How to proceed next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work because you will always receive a `string` from your `textField`. I guess, you want to let the user enter something like `1, 2, 3` and then check, if each of these values is an integer, right?

You could use a regular text field like:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'marks') ?>
```

And then write a custom validator:

```
array('marks', 'validateIntegerList')

public function validateIntegerList($attribute, $params)
{
    $message = isset($params['message']) ? 
        $params['message'] : 'Please only enter integers!';

    $value = $this->$attribute;

    // User entered single number -> OK
    if(ctype_digit(trim($value)) && strpos($value, ',')===false)
        return;

    // User entered list of numbers -> Check each
    foreach( explode(',', $this->$attribute) as $value) {
        if(!ctype_digit(trim($value))) {
            $this->addError($attribute, $message);
            return;
        }
    }
 }
```

You may have to tweak the validation logic a little. But it should give you some idea.

Comment: Harti... Thanks fr d quick reply. bro in view i have put textfield inside d foreach. so in controller i wil b retrieving it like array[pos]. Hope u understood.

Comment: Even in that case you can write a custom validator. You should be able to modify my example to work with `$attribute` being an array. We can't do your job here ;)